# Sql query for selecting data out of an table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I`m working on a project that is examining Colorectal Cancer. And i have some data that i want to filter with an Sql query. The problem is that some of the experiments have failed so that some of the samples are in another folder pointed with _2 or _3 if its the second or third time this experiment was tried.

My data looks as follows:

[image]

So i want to check if Sentrix_ID exists more than 1 time if so than the query should take the latest version _2 or _3 and so one. Is there any Query that will do that for me.

And the raw_data:

```
ID  Sample_Name Sample_Code Sample  Sentrix_ID  NorTum  Pool_ID Sample_Group    Sentrix_Position    Folderdate  opmerkingen
1835    99-02872T2  99-02872T2  99-02872    1495455 T2  GS0006564-OPA   HNPCC_UV    R001_C010   Exp060501   MLH1-UV
1836    97-5332T1   97-5332T1   97-5332 1495455 T1  GS0006564-OPA   MUTYH   R001_C011   Exp060501   1105delC_G382D
1827    R02-81709N  R02-81709N  R02-81709   1495455 N   GS0006563-OPA   HNPCC_UV    R001_C002   Exp060501   MSH2
492 t03-32120 N t03-32120 N t03-32120   1495455_2   N   GS0006563-OPA   TEM_TME_LOH R004_C005   Exp060920   
484 t02-27628 N t02-27628 N t02-27628   1495455_2   N   GS0006563-OPA   TEM_TME_LOH R004_C004   Exp060920   
478 t03-06297 B2    t03-06297 B2    t03-06297   1495455_2   B2  GS0006563-OPA   TEM_TME_LOH R006_C003   Exp060920   
479 t03-06297 B3    t03-06297 B3    t03-06297   1495455_2   B3  GS0006563-OPA   TEM_TME_LOH R007_C003   Exp060920
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly does the query need to return? I.e. which fields

Comment: I can write a stored procedure solution for this after fetching the list based on a particular sentrix id and then processing for the greatest subset.

Comment: Assume that he is trying to fetch all the rows where sentrix id is like XXXX_<greatest-value>

Comment: Well i first tried it with In but there you cant add a decision point. 
So now i thought maybe there is an reg expression or something like that that can solve the problem

Comment: Does MS Access support CTEs? If so I can provide a quick solution

Comment: Posting pictures is pointless as people need data to test. Please post actual data, not an image. It does not matter how badly formatted it is, just cut-and-paste.

Comment: Since when does MS Access support CTEs? Are you using MS Access with Jet/ACE or have you an SQL Server back-end?

Comment: When I said it did not matter how badly formatted, it should at least include line breaks.

Comment: WElll i looked it up and it seems that till acces 2010 it supports CTEs. And ill try to format the data some more:)

Comment: MS Access has *never* supported CTEs. Where is your reference that days it does?

Comment: WEll if you say so i`m assuming youre right some people say that its implemented in sql`99 and should work till acces 2010. Can you give me an other option to do the job?

Comment: There is no way to tell from your sample data which records should be returned. There are three records with sentrix_id 1495455 and four with 1495455_2. All other fields are either wildly different or exactly as each other. To select a sepecif row, one would expect a field that identifies the series and then the various sentrix_id, so `experiment1,1495455;experiment1,1495455_2;experiment1,1495455_3` and so on. i cannot see anything like this in the sample data.

Comment: Thanks @remou for the good explanation, i know what you mean, but i need all the entrys with the highest experiment number so if there are 5 with _2 and 5 with _3 i want to take the one with _3.

Comment: You say "5 with _3 i want to take the one with _3." This is contradictory. If there are **five** with _3, how do you take the **one** with _3? This is exactly the problem that your sample data shows. Which of the **four** with _2 do you want?

Comment: @Remou All of them this is the data folder NAME and its used for the identification of other unique sample names like t03-32120

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to parse the value in your sentrix_id column into a prefix and suffix?  You can use the instr() function to identify the position of the underscore, if any, unless you know the length of the prefix is always the same.

Try something like

```
select *, 
left(sentrix_id,8) as prefix,
iif(len(sentrix_id) = 8 ,"",mid(sentrix_id,10)) as suffix
from table
```

if you create a new query with equivalent sql, you should see two additional rows in your table, one for the ID and one for the version suffix.

Then, using those query results in a second new query, you can group by prefix and return the max(suffix).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [YourTable] WHERE [Sentrix_ID] LIKE '<value>%' ORDER BY [Sentrix_ID] DESC
```

Would that work for your problem?

Comment: Nope no i`m getting an empty table while setting the value to _2

Comment: Oh hang on, use Like instead? Is that any better? Where I've put <value> use the name without the suffix, like John not John_2. This should then give you the John test with the highest suffix, though you would have to be sure the names are unique enough to avoid clashes when using Like

Comment: Hmmm i`m getting an error in the Order BY clausule, when  using DESC limit. I`m using acces to insert the SQL code.

Comment: My bad, just edited it and ran it on my local machine and it works now

Comment: Yeah i runs now, but now i`m having an empty table. i`ve filled in the value part with this:  LIKE '149%' ORDER BY [Sentrix_ID] DESC

Comment: The column name after the WHERE clause is the one you want to search for the value in the LIKE statement. Maybe that isnt the Sentrix_Id, maybe you actually want to search the Sample Code, and then order by the Sentrix_Id still to find out the number of tests needed for a particular sample code?

Comment: Well i need to check the Sentrix_ID And it should pick the highest folder so if there is 1495455_2 and 1495455_3 it should pick tree but the problem is that 1495455 is not the only folder there also is 1281037 and so on and on.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT count(Sentrix_ID) AS senId 
    FROM tableName 
    GROUP BY Sentrix_ID
) AS m  
WHERE senId = 1;
```

This query will results if Sentrix_ID exists more than 1 it will give the latest version but in above question it will show you the empty table because Sentrix_id(1495455 & 1495455_2) has repeated more than one times. So if you have _3 as one entry in the table means it will give the _3 data.

Comment: This statement also gives an empty table.

Comment: yeah!the reason is  Sentrix_id(1495455 & 1495455_2) has repeated more than one times..